# PGFPLOT bar graph possition legend and different notation

Tags: pgfplots, graphs, legend

I would like to ask you about the bar graph and possition legend.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        [ xbar,
        %enlargelimits=0.14,width=8cm,height=6cm,,
            bar width=10pt,area legend,legend pos=south east,
            legend style={cells={anchor=west}}, area legend,
            tick align=outside,xlabel=\textbf{EUR Billion},
            ytick={1,...,3},
            yticklabel style={text width=3.3cm,align=right},
            yticklabels={Automotive \& Aircraft,
                                        Building Sector,ICT}]

      \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue!15]
                        coordinates {(42,1) (34.5,2) (42,3)};

        \addlegendentry{\textsc{2016}}

        \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue!50]
                        coordinates {(16.5,1) (15,2) (11.25,3)};


        \addlegendentry{\textsc{2006}}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I have this: 
[image: I have this one]

But I want the following:
[image: I want this one]

Thank you in advance for your time and help. Thge second figure was changed in Paint.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Just a tiny detail: MWE doesn't have a `\documentclass` (though in this case, it's not an issue at all :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering of the legend corresponds to the ordering of the plots, it can be reversed by the `reverse legend` option. The legend position can be modified through `legend style={at={(x,y)}}`. Note that `x`,`y` are here normalized coordinates.. See the code below.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [ xbar,
            bar width=10pt,area legend,legend pos=south east,
            reverse legend,
            legend style={cells={anchor=west},at={(0.99,0.42)}}, area legend,
            tick align=outside,xlabel=\textbf{EUR Billion},
            ytick={1,...,3},
            yticklabel style={text width=3.3cm,align=right},
            yticklabels={Automotive \& Aircraft,
                                        Building Sector,ICT}]

        \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue!15]
            coordinates {(42,1) (34.5,2) (42,3)};
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{2016}}                            

        \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue!50]
            coordinates {(16.5,1) (15,2) (11.25,3)};
        \addlegendentry{\textsc{2006}}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it and/or upvote it.